# 301 Redirect URLs starting with a specific keyword

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect all URLs staring with a specific word using RedirectMatch.

Let's say I need to redirect any URL that starts with the keyword "pdf" should be redirected to the base URL.

Requirement:

```
http://www.example.com/pdf         -> http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/pdf-444-abc -> http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/blog/pdf-abc-1234          -> must not redirect
http://www.example.com/images/web/pdf/1234568.jpg -> must not redirect
```

I have used the following 301 redirect rule and it redirects all above examples.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /pdf(.*)$ http://www.example.com/
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching only starting characters use '^' (caret)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/pdf(.*) http://www.example.com/
```